# How to view division of Linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra, and am concerned with division by scalar of a linear combination. I need a visual or algebraic proof for proving the impossibility of division of a linear combination by its constituent vectors (in general case), with the basic case being for 2 vectors. A reference will also suffice.

I can go only as far as:

Let us take two vectors: a) (2, 3, 0); b) (3, 5,0).

I have specifically taken a complex number to represent the vector, or alternately will have a vector in the Cartesian plane. In fact, I feel that only two dimensions need be taken, but need help on whether keeping the third dimension empty will work.

Let us take a simple linear combination of the two vectors by having a multiplier of 2 and 3 respectively.

Now, the linear combination is : 2(2, 3, 0) + 3(3, 5, 0) => (4+6, 6+15, 0)

The issue of proving either graphically or algebraically is what remains. It may happen (although, not possible when say in Cartesian plane the first number is $\sqrt 13$, and the second vector has magnitude - $4$) that this linear combination is divided; but even this simple division will help.

Comment: There is no defined operation for division, so it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Great. But, I hope the reason must be linked to something simple. If the reason is also stated, then it makes the picture clearer. May be just the same cause as for the matrix division being not defined. But, to base linear algebra totally on matrices confuses beginner, like me. Also, for matrices still the equivalent operation of multiplication by an inverse matrix (if it exists) is defined. Is there such an option available for division for vectors?

Comment: The problem is that matrix multiplication isn't really multiplication... Think of a matrix as function, that maps vectors in one space to vectors in another space.  And matrix multiplication as the composition of functions.  There is no inverse operation to function composition.  Either you are composing two functions or you are not.  But, you can compose a function with its inverse function, and you can multiply a matrix by its matrix inverse.  As for linear algebra being based on matrices.  That is what linear algebra is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wanted to comment after reading about inverses and practicing with it, but it would take some time. I wished such informal content were in books, that surmised the core of the subject. If you know of any reference that states comparison or a summary of the subject, please tell.

Comment: Watch the 3 blue 1 brown series on linear algebra.  It is a nice introduction.